# How do I run a local executable in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

Quite lost with this one. I can demonstrate the issue with this simple Gitlab CI:

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.29.0
  entrypoint: ['']

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cp /root/temp/smctl smctl
    - ls -ltrh
    - chmod +x smctl
    - ./smctl --help
```

I get the following result:

1. File gets copied
2. **ls** shows the **smctl** file exists in the current directory
3. When I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

   `/bin/sh: eval: line 154: ./smctl: not found`

What is going on here? Thanks

Comment: What is the file `/root/temp/smctl` and how did you put it there? Where did that binary come from? I could be mistaken, but I don't think it's part of the `docker/compose` image. Was it compiled for the correct architecture/platform? My guess is that your binary is not compatible. If you run `file ./smctl` what does it say?

Comment: I get this: "/bin/sh: eval: line 154: file: not found". I don't want this to be part of a Docker image as it's just a binary I thought I could just copy and run.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the packet is installed on the docker image `docker/compose:1.29.0` and not on the host machine, otherwise you'll need to install it either with `before_script` or directly in `script`.

Comment: I do see that file though when I run: "ls -ltrh". I also copy the file into the working directory with: - "cp /root/temp/smctl smctl". The file is not part of the Docker image and that's by design. I need this binary for this one stage in the build process.

Comment: If you're using an auto-hosted runner, you can attach a volume to the various images used in the jobs.
In the configuration file`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

`volumes = ["/path/to/bin/in/hosted_host:/path/to/bin/in/docker_image:rw"]`

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#volumes-in-the-runnersdocker-section

Comment: You can use a docker image that include smctl

Comment: Actually the "/root/temp/smctl" is done via the "volumes" configuration. As described, I can "see" the file when I run "ls" but not when I execute it. That is my issue